# Shouldn't an IoC container be handling serialization of business logic singletons?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

The statements and a following question below are based on my own experience, and if some are incorrect, you are free to point it out. In fact, I would really appreciate it.

In almost any application architecture, a developers make use of an IoC container resolved class instances, that are `InSingletonScope()` (terminology taken from Ninject, but I am sure most will get the meaning).

An example of a class instance, that you only need one of, could be an implementation of ICloudStorageProvider for example.

If an ICloudStorageProvider implementation instance is comprising a login data to the cloud account in a form of a nested LoginData class, or just the plain Login and Password fields, so far I've been calling a method like `LocalStorageProvider.SaveLoginData(...)` whenever I needed to persist it. A different class, that knew how to do it, saved the data for my class instance.

It would make a life much easier, if there was a mechanism, that allowed serializing to a local data store an entire instances of such "singleton" objects, and then, when the app is restarted, or an isntance is needed again, it would just deserialize it along with the login data in the above example.

And since IoC container is the one responsible for an object instantiation nowadays, is seems like a perfect match for such a responsibility.

Is there such a mechanism, that acts as both, IoC and serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd want to do such a thing, but it sounds to me like it would be best modeled as a custom lifetime style. Basically, it's a lifestyle that extends *beyond* Singleton and spans multiple container instances.

However, in most cases, Singleton services tend to be stateless, in which case serializing them doesn't make much sense.

Whether or not it's possible to write a custom lifetime for Ninject I can't say, but custom lifetimes are supported in [Castle Windsor](http://castleproject.org/container/index.html), [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) and [Unity](http://unity.codeplex.com/).

A related question is exactly *how* you'd serialize an arbitrary object graph? In .NET, the easiest way is to use the built-in binary serializer, but that requires that all objects in the graph are annotated with the [Serializable] attribute or implement ISerializable. There are also other options, but most require some sort of opt-in mechanism, so it's severely going to constrain which services can serialized.